# covert vector of strings to array of strings

Tags: c++, c

Hello I have a problem in my code.  I want to convert vector of strings in C++ to array of strings in C but I got a error "double free or corruption (out):"
in my code I have two functions
C++ function: `void get_num_apn( unsigned int *num_apn , char **arr)` : that convert the vector of strings to array of strings
C function : in my C function I have called `get_num_apn` but I need to call this function one time
any one can help please and thanks.

c++ code:

```
void get_num_apn( unsigned int *num_apn , char **arr)
{
     vector<std::string>apn={ "ghadz", "internet.ooredoo.tn",  "mms.ooredoo.tn","internet.tn","gprs.tn",
    "mms.tn",
    "weborange",
    "mms.otun" }   ;
    *num_apn=apn.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < apn.size(); i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = strdup(apn[i].c_str());
    } 
}
```

c code :

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int num_apn=0;
    char **arr = NULL;
    arr = (char**)malloc(num_apn*sizeof(char*));
    get_num_apn(&num_apn, arr);
    for (int i=0 ; i<num_apn ; i++)
    {
        printf("arr[i]=%s\n" , arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <num_apn; i++) 
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num_apn` is 0 during `malloc()`. So in `get_num_apn()` you are doing invalid memory access. Same during free

Comment: yes this problem how i can  solve it ?

Comment: how about allocate the double pointer in `get_num_apn()` and then copy the individual apn?

Comment: i have  tried this and i got fault segmentation

Comment: You may also be interested in [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/11082165) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165)

Comment: @ François Andrieux if you have any idea tell please ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, but `strdup()` will allocate and then copy the content of the string. right?

Comment: as i know just copy the content of strings

Comment: @kuro Hadn't noticed that, you're right.

Comment: no one have any idea ?

Comment: Running under Valgrind will give you insights quicker than asking the community.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Casting the result of malloc is appropriate in C-like code compiled by a C++ compiler.

Comment: As for quick insights... free corruption -> aha problem with allocation -> check malloc -> does it make sense -> no it doesn't. That's less than one minute of debugging, no need for Valgrind or SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know how many strings there are before calling `get_num_apn`, so you don't know how much space to pre-allocate.  The example code ends up allocating nothing, with the result that `get_num_apn` attempts some invalid memory accesses.  There are multiple possible solutions, but they all fall into two broad categories:

- provide a way for the caller to determine in advance how much space to allocate, or
- have `get_num_apn` perform the allocation.

In the example code, `get_num_apn` relies on private, internal information about the data to be copied, and in such a case, it seems most sensible to exercise the second alternative.

The next question is how `get_num_apn` should provide results to the caller.  You again have two good options: via its parameters or via its return value.  Or both.  To deliver the array pointer itself via a parameter would require a triple pointer, which is stylistically nasty, but you do need to return the array length as well.

The simplest way forward would be to `return` the array pointer, and provide the length via an out parameter as you already do.  However, you have indicated in comments that you want to reserve the return value for another purpose, so the next simplest way is to provide both the array pointer and the length via out parameters.  For example:

```
// C++

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

extern "C" char *strdup(const char *);

extern "C"
void get_num_apn(unsigned int *num_apn, char ***arr) {
    std::vector<std::string> apn = {
         "ghadz", "internet.ooredoo.tn", "mms.ooredoo.tn", "internet.tn",
         "gprs.tn", "mms.tn", "weborange", "mms.otun"
    };

    char **temp = (char **) malloc(apn.size() * sizeof(*temp));

    if (!temp) {
        *num_apn = 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < apn.size(); i++) {
            temp[i] = strdup(apn[i].c_str());
        } 
        *num_apn = apn.size();
    }

    *arr = temp;
}
```

```
// C

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void get_num_apn(unsigned int *num_apn, char ***arr);

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num_apn = 0;
    char **arr;

    get_num_apn(&num_apn, &arr);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_apn; i++) {
        printf("arr[i]=%s\n", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

That could be made safer by checking for and handling `strdup()` failures, of course, but that's not what I'm demonstrating.

Comment: i need the type of "get_num_apn" is  unsigned int because  i have another variable to return

Comment: @sarra, if you need the function's return value for another purpose -- which you did not disclose in the question -- then you can deliver the array pointer via an out parameter, as this answer already indicates.  Note well that that requires an additional level of indirection, hence my remark about triple pointers.

Comment: @ John Bollinger can you edit your solution as i need because i dont understand well what you mean ?

Comment: Ok, @sarra, done.  In the future, please present all your requirements up front.

Comment: hello  
John Bollinger  why i got this error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2"

Comment: @sarra, for some reason outside the scope of this answer.  I have made minor updates to show exact, complete code for a compilable demo program.  If I compile it and run it under Valgrind or with relevant AddressSanitizer options then they do not detect any double free or other misuse.